# Can I develop touch desktop applications? (i.e. not Metro Style)

Tags: c#, winforms, touch

I seem to be having a hard time finding the answer to my question via Google.  I just want to know whether the touch interactions used in metro style apps can be utilized from regular desktop applications in Windows 8 as well?

Comment: Not sure about winforms (though I assume so) but for WPF, there are definitely touch and pen events. You might have to figure out how to handle gestures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; think of it this way; touch capability is really a hardware feature, and that hardware must then have drivers available for the target OS. Code can then be written to interact with those drivers.

DevExpress controls, for example, have been touch enabled from 2011 onwards if I recall correctly.

https://www.devexpress.com/subscriptions/dxperience/dxv2/?page=3

Also; found this, thought it might be useful to the OP:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/developing-windows-8-desktop-touch-apps-with-windows-presentation-foundation

Comment: Ditto - I had some of those old dinosaur WinForms running on tablets ages ago. There were no code changes required, works just like a mouse. As Magus notes pen support is the key. I think the early efforts where called Win XP Tablet PC Edition. My WinForms are working fine on a Win 8 Surface Pro desktop using touch.

Comment: @rheitzman Yeah, I knew it could do that.  But I was forgetting about the hardware support aspect... was really wondering if I could implement some touch features on a regular touch screen monitor (ie. swiping and such, not just clicking) but I don't think the type of touch screen monitors we use typically have 'touch' enabled hardware... they just mimic mouse clicks.  I'll have to find out for sure though.